# What does it mean when someone says "Oi" as a response to a greeting?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’ve had a few interactions with people from countries other than my own, and when I greet them, oftentimes they’re response is just "Oi." What does that mean in this context? Where is it typically used (country) and is it a new thing, or has it been around for a long time, and I’m only just catching on...?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: Linguistics.SE, which deals with various languages.

Comment: It's like responding "Hey!" in the US. (In fact it's a British pronunciation of "hey")

Comment: It can be used as a greeting, but it is more commonly used (in the UK) as a rather coarse wsy of attracting someone's attention. Avoid, is my recommendation.

Comment: In the UK I do not think it would be a response, except to warn you to not do something the speaker objected to.

Comment: People who say 'Oi' in Britain are _very common_ and you should, as has been said, avoid them.

Comment: @Oldbag - in fact "hey" is a US pronunciation of 'Oi'.

Answer (score 1):

```
Oi:
```

> An informal greeting, similar to hi. *Oi! How's it going?*

(Wiktionary)

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/oi

Comment: In UK it would be considered rude to attract someone's attention with "Oi!" It's usually in a context such as "Oi! Who do you think you're looking at?" or "Oi! That's my property you are walking on."